# jQuery how to keep the style value when going back

Tags: jquery, store

I've got an issue with the keeping style value when coming back to a page from another.

I've got a code in jQuery that is showing my menu.

```
$( "#burger" ).click(function() {
    if ($("#burger").hasClass("closed")) {
      $( "#menu" ).animate({
        marginLeft: "-400px"
      }, 600, function() {
        $("#burger").removeClass("closed");
        $("#burger").addClass("open");
      });
    } else {
        $( "#menu" ).animate({
        marginLeft: 0
      }, 600, function() {
        $("#burger").removeClass("open");
        $("#burger").addClass("closed");
      });
    }
});
```

And now when i enter other link: for example "gallery.html" and then go back to the "index.html" the menu is no longer there.

How can i keep the margin-left:-400px; in the memory, so when i go back the menu will still be there?

Also i don't wanna to menu will be open everytime i go back, cause in some cases it will be closed and it should remain - so in that case the value should be remembered as "margin-left:0px;"

Thanks for answers!

Comment: You need to store the information if the menu should be open or closed somewhere, a cookie perhaps ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's going on is that JQuery or any JS based language works on the client, so when you reload the page or your app cause a Postback every change the JQuery had done will be erased. As posted by zfrisch the best method is to "save" that the user has already clicked on the item and base it's position on whether or not has been changed.

```
//if you are interested on keeping it this way until browser is erased manually
localStorage.itemClicked = true;
//if the configuration is going to be reset on everytime the user opens his browser
sessionStorage.itemClicked = true;
```

and in the .ready function you change its position

```
$(function(){
    if(localStorage.itemClicked){
        $('#burger').addClass("open");
        $('#burger').css({margin-left:"-400px"});
    }
});
```

and your click event should look like this

```
$( "#burger" ).click(function() {
    if ($("#burger").hasClass("closed")) {

      $( "#menu" ).animate({
        marginLeft: "-400px"
      }, 600, function() {
        $("#burger").removeClass("closed");
        $("#burger").addClass("open");

        //save that was clicked
        localStorage.itemClicked = true;
      });
    } else {

        $( "#menu" ).animate({
        marginLeft: 0
      }, 600, function() {
        $("#burger").removeClass("open");
        $("#burger").addClass("closed");

        //remove the key so it is not wasting memory
        localStorage.removeItem("itemClicked");
      });
    }
});
```

Hope it helped

Comment: I've tryed this solution... but in this case menu is always open when i'm coming back or refreshing the window, no matter if i opened it in the first place

Comment: that means it is evaluating localStorage.itemClicked as true every time could you please post the result of console.log(localStorage.itemClicked) or a print of the Storage section of the inspector so I can provide a little help

Comment: i've make it working by putting localStorage.itemClicked = true; after animation completed - don't know how, but it works, please fix that in your post, so i can mark is as a good answer.

Comment: changed it now, it should work either way I'm looking why right now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle to round out this answer [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/42r6c5ke/1/)

You can add an item with HTML5 Storage API using sessionStorage or localStorage.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("leftset", "yes");
localStorage.setItem("leftset", "yes");
```

the difference is that localStorage will save it indefinitely on the users computer. Session storage will remove it when the browser window is closed.

You can use

```
sessionStorage.getItem("leftset");
localStorage.getItem("leftset");
```

To pull from the storage object on page load or dom ready and then execute whether or not "leftset"(in this example, but you can set it up as whatever) has a value.

if you would like to remove an item from storage you can use the following:

```
sessionStorage.removeItem("leftset");
localStorage.removeItem("leftset");
```

learn more at [w3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) or check out the demo [HTML5 Storage Demo](http://html5demos.com/storage)